# Every time my cointainer restarts, I see more files in volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am using docker-compose to mount multiple images, and wanted to create celery worker, but each time container restarts, I see more files in it. I have no idea why it is happening.
My goal was to build one image, and use current files in container via volume. So my local files are the same in container.

```
# Console output
worker_1        | Readme.md
worker_1        | __init__.py
worker_1        | __pycache__
worker_1        | api.py
worker_1        | custom_logger.py
worker_1        | database_operator.py
worker_1        | secret_token.txt
worker_1        | tasks.py
worker_1        | tweet_operator.py
twitteranalyzer_worker_1 exited with code 0
worker_1        | Readme.md
worker_1        | __init__.py
worker_1        | __pycache__
worker_1        | api.py
worker_1        | custom_logger.py
worker_1        | database_operator.py
worker_1        | secret_token.txt
worker_1        | tasks.py
worker_1        | tweet_operator.py
worker_1        | Readme.md
worker_1        | __init__.py
worker_1        | __pycache__
worker_1        | api.py
worker_1        | custom_logger.py
worker_1        | database_operator.py
worker_1        | secret_token.txt
worker_1        | tasks.py
worker_1        | tweet_operator.py
worker_1        | Readme.md
worker_1        | __init__.py
worker_1        | __pycache__
worker_1        | api.py
worker_1        | custom_logger.py
worker_1        | database_operator.py
worker_1        | secret_token.txt
worker_1        | tasks.py
worker_1        | tweet_operator.py
twitteranalyzer_worker_1 exited with code 0
worker_1        | Readme.md
worker_1        | __init__.py
worker_1        | __pycache__
worker_1        | api.py
worker_1        | custom_logger.py
worker_1        | database_operator.py
worker_1        | secret_token.txt
worker_1        | tasks.py
worker_1        | tweet_operator.py
worker_1        | Readme.md
worker_1        | __init__.py
worker_1        | __pycache__
worker_1        | api.py
worker_1        | custom_logger.py
worker_1        | database_operator.py
worker_1        | secret_token.txt
worker_1        | tasks.py
worker_1        | tweet_operator.py
worker_1        | Readme.md
worker_1        | __init__.py
worker_1        | __pycache__
worker_1        | api.py
worker_1        | custom_logger.py
worker_1        | database_operator.py
worker_1        | secret_token.txt
worker_1        | tasks.py
worker_1        | tweet_operator.py
worker_1        | Readme.md
worker_1        | __init__.py
worker_1        | __pycache__
worker_1        | api.py
worker_1        | custom_logger.py
worker_1        | database_operator.py
worker_1        | secret_token.txt
worker_1        | tasks.py
worker_1        | tweet_operator.py
worker_1        | Readme.md
worker_1        | __init__.py
worker_1        | __pycache__
worker_1        | api.py
worker_1        | custom_logger.py
worker_1        | database_operator.py
worker_1        | secret_token.txt
worker_1        | tasks.py
worker_1        | tweet_operator.py
twitteranalyzer_worker_1 exited with code 0
```

I just run simple ls in bash to see why it happend, but I have no clue or should I even worry about it. dockerfile `CeleryWorker` is just installing python dependencies.

```
# docker-compose.yaml
...
  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: CeleryWorker
    image: celeryworker:1.0
    volumes:
      - ./twitter_analyzer/analyzer:/app/
    links:
      - broker
    depends_on:
      - broker
    restart: always
    command: bash -c "ls"
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker's general expectation is that a container will contain a long-running process, like a Web server.  The `restart:` option tells it what to do when that process exits.

In your case you're not running a long-running process; you're invoking a shell to just run `/bin/ls`.  When that exits, the `restart: always` takes effect, and it runs the container command again.  That will exit promptly, and when it exits, the `restart:always` takes effect...

You probably don't need the `command:` in `docker-compose.yml` at all, especially if you have a dedicated Dockerfile for the worker process.  If you do have a `command:`, it should start the Celery worker.  If you want to override it with a short-lived command, don't set a restart policy.  (Also remember that you can use [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) to run a one-off alternate command, for example for a debugging shell.)

```yaml
worker:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: CeleryWorker
  # (Sets the image name `docker-compose build` builds.)
  image: celeryworker:1.0
  # Do not need volumes: since the code is in the image
  # Do not need links: on modern Docker at all
  depends_on:
    - broker
  restart: always
  # Do not need command: since CMD is in the Dockerfile
```

Comment: you absolutely missed the point, i need volumes, I don't want rebuild image every time I run project with new files and pull all dependencies, going further i did not copied files in DockerFile, thats why Im runing command in compose

Comment: A Python virtual environment might better suit your needs.  It uses an isolated package set so that it doesn't interfere with the system Python, but it's also based on the local filesystem so it doesn't have the inconveniences an all-Docker setup brings.

Comment: If you're running a Docker Compose setup with `command: ls` and `restart: always`, then it will run `ls` in an infinite loop, which matches the behavior you're reporting.

Comment: I changed `ls` to some invalid command and prompt kept growing.... so files are fine, I wonder why with each restart i keeps posting new logs + older ones